# function reference inside a array into wordpress add_action ,error is Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress

```
class xxx {
    public $_handle;
    public function admin_entry(){
        $this->_handle = array(
            'cpt_init_interface' => function(){
                do stuff ...
            },
            'scripts_enqueue_interface' => function(){
                do stuff ... 
            }
        );

    }

}

$xxx1 = new xxx();
add_action('init',$xxx1->_handle['cpt_init_interface']);
```

error:Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in /Users/.../wp-includes/plugin.php on line 900

I just simply wanna a array within function as its values (organised in a class ) and process it as a function name string into the add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, 10, 1 ).

I used to be a C coder and much confusing with php.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

When using the [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function, you need to pass the class name and function you want to callback as an array. The following code will auto run on new instances of the class. You can have the action outside the class and call the class name as a string, but this adds a little autonomy to it for ease of use.

```
class xxx {
    public $_handle;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'admin_entry' ), 10 );
    }

    public static function admin_entry(){
        $this->_handle = array(
            'cpt_init_interface' => function(){
                do stuff ...
            },
            'scripts_enqueue_interface' => function(){
                do stuff ... 
            }
        );
    }
}

$xxx1 = new xxx();
```

Comment: Hi,James.Thanks for your answer .What i want is to store a collection of functions inside array and using specific one of which as function reference to hook onto different $tags in the add_action .@Daniel James